# How to correct "Error in default port dimensions function of S-function 'X'.function doesnt fully set the dimensions of output port x" under Simulink?

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink

I'm a master's student and i'm studying electrical engineering - control systems. 
I've been assigned (by my Supervisor professor) to simulate a feedback linearization control method so I chose a paper (attached below) and I made a simulink model for it. The problem is when I try to run the simulation, it gives the error: 
Error in default port dimensions function of S-function 'FeedbackLinearization/Controller'. This function does not fully set the dimensions of output port 2
So i turned on the signal dimensions display to check for signal dimensions and check whether i've made an error or not. I see a problem for the 'e' signal. It should be a 3*1 vector that indicates error for tracking x-y-z. As you can see, output of the mux the dimension is 3 so everything is ok. the problem is when the signal reaches a block (MATLAB function or derivative) its dimension reduces down to one. I have attached my slx model so you please be kind and take a look. 
I've checked both Controller Matlab func and Plant Matlab func and they are working fine. 
Please help me. This is so vital for me! Thank you for your time, and consideration!

the paper: 
http://uupload.ir/view/z9mg_aminfl.pdf/

the potential problem occurs here:
http://uupload.ir/files/jc3k_capture.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In models, when there are feedback loops, sometimes dimensions cannot be propagated successfully if the input sizes depend on the output sizes. This model may be in that category. For solving this case, you should insert a "Signal Specification" block at a location where you know the sizes. For example, at the output of mux.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/signalspecification.html?s_tid=doc_ta

If you insert this block at the output of the Mux where you have circled, you can set the dimension parameter to 3 and all others as default.